# Does not match in any class?

Tags: c++

I've encountered an issue when testing my code.

```
   void Library::checkOutBook(std::string pID, std::string bID); {
   bool patronIDMatch = false, bookIDMatch = false;
   int bookOnFile=-1, patronOnFile=-1;
   for (int i=0; i<members.size(); i++) {
      if (pID==members[i].getIdNum()) {
         patronIDMatch=true;
         patronOnFile=i;
         break;
      }
      else continue;
```

for the first line here, I'm getting the following errors:

> Library.cpp:68: error: prototype for ‘void Library::checkOutBook(std::string, std::string)’ does not match any in class ‘Library’
>
> Library.cpp:68: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘{’ token

But I'm matching it as it appears in my Library class as such

```
        //Library.hpp
    #ifndef LIBRARY_HPP
    #define LIBRARY_HPP
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include "Patron.hpp"

    class Library {

    private:
       std::vector<Book*> holdings;
       std::vector<Patron*> members;
       int currentDate;

    public:
       Library();
       void addBook(Book*);
       void addPatron(Patron*);
       std::string checkOutBook(std::string pID, std::string bID);
       std::string returnBook(std::string bID);
       std::string requestBook(std::string pID, std::string bID);
       std::string payFine(std::string pID, double payment);
       void incrementCurrentDate();
       Patron* getPatron(std::string pID);
       Book* getBook(std::string bID);
    };
    #endif
```

How would I go about fixing this?

**i am prohibited from altering the header file unfortunately :(**

edit:

```
    void Library::returnBook(std::string bID); {
```

bool bookIDMatch=false;
   string tempPatronID;
   int bookOnFile=-1;
   for (int i=0; i

Comment: It's a shame you're not allowed to modify the header, because whoever created it could use a lesson in const-correctness and passing strings as parameters, among other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't match because the function you're trying to define returns `void`:

```
void Library::checkOutBook(std::string pID, std::string bID)
```

but the declaration in the `Library` class says it returns `std::string`:

```
std::string checkOutBook(std::string pID, std::string bID);
```

Also, remove that semicolon between the `)` and the `{` in the function header.

Comment: That's so strange! I included a bit of code at the bottom of my post where I also defined a function that returns void, but for some reason it's not giving me an error? How would I write the code here then :( sorry for the trouble!

Comment: @cdante Is that function below this one? It's possible that the semicolon confused the compiler so much it never got that far.

Comment: @cdante And if you're wondering *why* that little semicolon might totally confuse the compiler... it's because that semicolon means all the stuff between `{` and `}` is not inside the function.

Comment: ah, alright makes sense. btw any idea what "Library.cpp: At global scope:" means? not understanding this error eaither

Comment: @c.dante That is part of the error before or after that line. "At global scope" means "Outside of any function or class" (it might or might not count namespaces as well)